# Type-safe extra control on a Story

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a `Chip` component that accepts an extra element from its `leftSection` prop, a `ReactNode`. One of the possible uses is to render a `ColorSwatch`.

Then, I have the following story metadata:

```
const meta = {
  component: Chip,
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
    leftSection: {
      control: 'select',
      options: ['none', 'swatch'],
    },
    swatchColor: {
      control: 'color',
      if: { arg: 'leftSection', eq: 'swatch' },
    },
  },
} as Meta<Component>;
```

The `Chip` component doesn't have the `swatchColor` prop. It's defined only on the storybook for editing its value on the storybook itself.

But when writing the story object, it raises a type error:

```
export const Default: StoryObj<Component> = {
  render: (args) => {
    const { leftSection, swatchColor, ...rest } = args;
    //                   ^ type error here: Property 'swatchColor' does not exist

    if (leftSection === 'swatch') {
      return (
        <Chip
          leftSection={<ColorSwatch color={swatchColor} />}
          {...rest}
        />
      );
    }

    return <Chip {...rest} />;
  },

  args: {
    label: 'foo',
    leftSection: 'none',
  },
};
```

Despite it works, I would like to fix the type error at the same time that I have type safety.

Is there a way to have extra controls on the story and still make the TS/Storybook happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can append on the component's `Prop` our custom story props, and use it instead of `Component`.

```
import Chip, { Props } from './Chip';

type CustomStoryProps = { swatchColor: string };
type Component = Props & CustomStoryProps;

const meta: Meta<Component> = {
  //        ^ type safer than using `as` ✅
}

export const Default: StoryObj<Component> = {
  render: (args) => {
    const { leftSection, swatchColor, ...rest } = args;
    //                   ^ no more errors ✅
```